# GameModeBase: InitGame vs InitGameState

Tags: unreal-engine4

- UE version: 4.17

Game state can be initialized in `FooGameMode::InitGameState`, then what is the purpose of `FooGameMode::InitGame` and `FooGameMode::PreInitializeComponents`?

For reference, the callstack seems like this:

```
UEngine::LoadMap
- UWorld::InitializeActorsForPlay
  - FooGameMode::InitGame
  - ULevel::RouteActorInitialize
    - FooGameMode::PreInitializeComponents
      - FooGameMode::InitGameState
```

Comment: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AGameMode/InitGame/index.html

Comment: And also gamemode vs gamestate:https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/122429/gamemode-vs-gamestate.html